# Detect and convert url in link and detect image and convert to img PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, image

Currently, I use this code to detect and convert URL in link in text.

But now, I need to keep this system, but detect and convert image too.

```
public function convert_to_link($text)
{
    $reg_user = '!@(.+)(?:\s|$)!U';
    if (preg_match_all($reg_user, $text, $matches))
    {
        return preg_replace($reg_user, '<a href="../userdetails.php?uname=$0" title="$0">$0</a>', $text);
    }
    $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
    if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {
        // make the urls hyper links
        if (preg_match("/\[img=([^\s'\"<>]+?)\]/i", $text))
        {
           //This is not working
            return preg_replace("/\[img=([^\s'\"<>]+?)\]/i", "<img border=0 src=\"\\1\">", $text);
        }
        else
        {
            return preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="$0" title="$0">$0</a> ', $text);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return $text;
    }
}
```

I use too [img][/img] code to convert image to  but with the code located above, the result is bad :

[image: Link]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your regex is looking for this format

```
[img=http://example.com/name.png]
```

but your example is in a different format

```
[img]http://example.com/name.png[/img]
```

a regex to identify the second form would be

```
"/^\[img\]([^\[]+)\[\/img\]$/i"
```

Comment: I try different way, same result with [img=] or [img][/img]

Comment: Can you provide a sample input along with what you expect the output to be?

Comment: I want when user share a text, the system detect and convert the link into <a href> ( currently it's working ) and detect and convert image to <img src> but currently, it only detect and convert link. In my system, I use bbcode to, so I want to convert image when user used [img] or [img=] tags

Comment: Have you tried changing the preg_replace to use `$1`